# Some bones won't move in pose mode

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode

Some bones wont move when I'm in pose mode. For example the head, the neck and the upper spike move without a problem. But when I try to move the eyes and the other spikes only the bones move not the mech. I've parented them all to the head. And did the weight painting myself. Does anyone know what may be wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I checked your file. There are no influences on the eye bones, but I can paint them in weight paint. And if I save the file and reload, it still works fine. So may be you missed something. Try to repaint the wiegths for the eye bones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the vertex groups for your weights but they are not assigned to the bones, simply rename the vertex group to the same name as the bone they are suppose to be assigned to and that should fix it.

[image: vertex groups]

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: No problem, for future reference with characters I would recommend using the Automatic weighting after selecting the mesh then armature hit Ctrl + P and select "With Automatic Weights" from the menu. This will create vertex groups automatically based on bone names then you just have to go in and make tweaks to your weights in weight paint mode.